# Web scraping com R 2

Tags: r

Eu gostaria de poder criar uma função no R para poder captar as informações desse site http://www.fns.saude.gov.br/visao/consulta/simplificada/filtro.jsf
sendo que ele me passa essas informações consolidadas por Ano, estado e Municipio, eu tentei utilizar o software R atraves da biblioteca "rvest" mas não entendi direito as funções
Alguém poderia me ajudar pelo menos como começar?

Comment: Olhe este link e veja se te ajuda: https://blog.rstudio.org/2014/11/24/rvest-easy-web-scraping-with-r/

Comment: Aparentemente, o acesso aos dados se dá por javascript, ou seja, você não conseguirá acessar os dados com o rvest. Deverá usar o RSelenium. Há muito bons tutoriais por aí. Segue um exemplo que mostra a limitação do rvest e parte para RSelenium: https://www.r-bloggers.com/navigating-scraping-a-job-site-rvest-rselenium/